# Lookup column In Sharepoint List

Tags: lookup

In my SHAREPOINT LIST, I have three fields - viz, FIRST NAME, LAST NAME, COMPANY NAME ( which is LOOKUP from COMPANIES)
I wish to create a fourth CALCULATED field ( based on OTHER COLUMNS of the SAME LIST ) by CONCATENATING FIRST NAME, LAST NAME and COMPANY NAME which is return from the LOOKUP.
In Column creation of the CALCULATE FIELD, "INSERT COLUMN" does not contain the COMPANY NAME field.
Please advise

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does not allow to insert lookup fields into calculation formula. one solution is create a workflow to fill your target column (concatenation of fields).
another solution is write event receiver to do above action for you.

Comment: Mr Zare, thank you for your prompt response. But I do not have a Sharepoint Designer option. Kindly advise